# Why do not pass the global variable values to functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

`var ViewId = $("#txt").val();` - I get value from a text box. And the id is `txt`. But the entered value do not pass to functions. It is only pass the value as `""`. And I add a number for the textbox. When it add all three functions one by one, it works. But when declared as a global it does not work.

```
    var ViewId = $("#txt").val();

    $("#btn2").click(function () {
        var msg = { "Message011": $("#txt1").val() }

        tv.login().done(function () {
            tv.createRecord(ViewId, msg).done(function () {
                alert("Data Added");
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: can you please add your HTML as well. It's hard to tell if there just is no value or if there is an error otherwise.

Comment: Move `var ViewId = $("#txt").val();` inside the `click` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :*Apply the function with inside the click and declare the variable as globel*

> **Why is not working ?**
>
> Because  global variable contain some function .its not with
>       string.SO its have document ready state to store the date to
>       variable.It need some action to store the data to the variable.

```
var ViewId =""
        $("#btn2").click(function () {
        ViewId = $("#txt").val();
        var msg = { "Message011": $("#txt1").val() }
            tv.login().done(function () {
             tv.createRecord(ViewId, msg).done(function () {
               alert("Data Added");
                 })
            })
        })
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of viewid inside the click event.
Otherwise it will take undefined if you get it outside.

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {
    var ViewId = $("#txt").val();
    var msg = { "Message011": $("#txt1").val() }

    tv.login().done(function () {

        tv.createRecord(ViewId, msg).done(function () {

            alert("Data Added");


        })
    })
})
```

Comment: OP says they're getting an empty string, not undefined, but still that would presumably be because it is getting the value from when the page first loaded and not the value as at the time of the click, so moving the `.val()` call is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable in global scope.

```
    var ViewId ="";
    jQuery(function(){
     $("#btn2").click(function () {
        ViewId = $("#txt").val();
        var msg = { "Message011": $("#txt1").val() }
            tv.login().done(function () {
             tv.createRecord(ViewId, msg).done(function () {
               alert("Data Added");
                 })
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: In the code shown, `ViewId` is only read once, so it can be declared locally inside the click handler.

Comment: Soloved. Thank you. :)